# Fossils on the Moon: Panspermia meets Conspiracy Theories!

Tags: internal-consistency, planets, space, moons, orbital-mechanics

This is an answer I found while looking up random factoids.  And it's gotten me wondering.
((*If I should take down the picture, and just paraphrase the text, please let me know.*))

[image: This is an answer in response to the effect she of spinning up the Earth's core.]

Charlie here is right, in that this is a fairly ridiculous theory.  However, the sheer ridiculousness of the concept reminded me of something that, while not *quite* as absurd as dinosaur fossils on Luna, is very similar in some aspects: Panspermia.

For those who need reminding, Panspermia is the concept that tiny and simplistic microbial life forms can be 'ejected' from their homeworlds by way of impact ejecta, hitch-hike on these wayward meteoroids, and then spread to other worlds when their host meteor impacts another planetary body.  Scientific experimentation on this theory (as of this date) has proven a bit iffy, but it's still a popular idea in sci-fi stories and video games.
That being said, let's look back at the lunacy (*nyuk-nyuk*) of the Dinosaurs on the Moon idea.  Suppose an incident similar to this happened earlier on in this planets history - say, when only microbial life forms exist on the surface.  As several documentaries have claimed, there are potential places where life forms can survive extreme heat, even in nigh-apocalyptic conditions.

Could a "Rapid Centrifugal Disintegration" event similar to this result in a planet and a moon with life forms derived from the same common ancestors?  How could life survive it?  Assuming they don't, could fossils of these microbial survivors even be found/survive to the civilized age?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The *rapid centrifugal* stuff is nonsense.

There *are* ways to blast rock off a planet though, including an incoming impact. We [have found rocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allan_Hills_84001) that came from other bodies and fallen to Earth, so it happens!

See the extended quote I included in [this answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21542/is-it-statistically-and-physically-possible-to-have-two-civilizations-in-the-sam/21656#21656) for current thoughts on *how could life survive it*.

Comment: Aye, I figured it were silliness.  Still, as the old saying goes, trying to thoroughly answer a very silly question can take you to some interesting places.  And thanks for the link!  I'm reading through it as I type.  :)